# Bacula: Client Run Before Job only al Full level

Tags: backup, bacula

I've set up a `bacula` Job that runs Client scripts before and after backup like this:

```
Job {
        Name = "my_job"
        Client = "my-fd"
        FileSet = "my-fset"
        Storage = "storage-File"
        Enabled = yes
        Schedule = "my_sched"
        Pool = "pool_full"
        JobDefs = "DefaultJob"
        #Max Start Delay = 3600
        Client Run Before Job = "/path/to/before/script.sh"
        Client Run After Job = "/path/to/after/script.sh"
}
```

By now is scheduled to run Full backups.

```
Schedule {
        Name = "my_sched"
        Run = Level=Full Pool="pool_full" mon-sun at 12:50
        }
```

I want to add a Incremental backup scheduled like this:

```
Run = Level=Incremental IncrementalPool="pool_incr" FullPool="pool_full" mon-sun at 21:21
```

**Question is:**

How to tell `bacula` that Incremental backup must not run Client scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution I found is providing JobLevel to the script as a argument with [`%l`](http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main/Configuring_Director.html)

```
    Client Run Before Job = "/path/to/before/script.sh %l"
    Client Run After Job = "/path/to/after/script.sh %l"
```

and arranging scripts like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
BACULA_J_LEVEL=$1

case $BACULA_J_LEVEL in

 Full)
  echo "Job Level $BACULA_J_LEVEL";
  #do stuff here
  exit 0
  ;;

 Differential)

  echo "Job Level $BACULA_J_LEVEL";
  # do nothing
  exit 0
  ;;

 Incremental)
  echo "Job Level $BACULA_J_LEVEL";
  # do nothing
  exit 0
  ;;

 *)

  echo "Level not recognized";
  exit 1;
  ;;

esac
```